# Spark "modifiedBefore" option while reading data from files

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am using Spark-2.4 to read files from hadoop.
The requirement is to read the files whose modified time is before some provided value.

I came across the spark documentation that mentions about the option `modifiedBefore`, please refer to the following spark doc [Modification Time Path Filters](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html#modification-time-path-filters), but I am not sure if it's available in spark 2.4, if not how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options `modifiedBefore` and `modifiedAfter` are available since Spark 3+ and can only be used in batch not streaming. For Spark 2.4, you can use Hadoop FileSystem [`globStatus`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#globStatus-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-) method and filter files using `getModificationTime`.

Here is an example of a function that takes a path and a threshold and returns list of file paths filtered using the threshold:

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

def getFilesModifiedBefore(path: Path, modifiedBefore: String) = {
  val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
  val thresHoldTime = format.parse(modifiedBefore).getTime()
  
  val files = path.getFileSystem(sc.hadoopConfiguration).globStatus(path)
  
  files.filter(_.getModificationTime < thresHoldTime).map(_.getPath.toString)

}
```

Then using it with `spark.read.csv` :

```scala
val df = spark.read.csv(getFilesModifiedBefore(new Path("/mypath"), "2021-03-17T10:46:12"):_*)
```

Comment: How can we handle this in streaming?